# Matlab Undefined variable "txt" or class "txt"

Tags: matlab, class, variables, undefined

I got this error in matlab 
Undefined variable "txt" or class "txt".
I know that i should define txt to solve the problem. The biggest problem is that i dont know what txt is. I have tried txt=1, but this didn't work. I have this code right now

```
    clr     =   [0 0 0 ; 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 1 1 0 ; 1 0 1 ; 0 1 1];
    style   =   [{'-'} {':'} {'--'} {'-.'}];
    nc      =   1;
    ns      =   1;
    n       =   1;
    l(n)    =   1;

    close all
    p       =   plot(XX,YY,'ro','MarkerFaceColor','b','MarkerSize',20);
    axis equal
    V       =   axis;
    r_x     =   (V(2) - V(1))/ 20;
    r_y     =   (V(4) - V(3))/ 20;
    axis([V(1)-r_x V(2)+r_x V(3)-r_y V(4)+r_y]);
    hold on
    for i=1:airports
        t(i)    =   text(XX(i),YY(i),['\bfA'num2str(i)],'HorizontalAlignment','Center','VerticalAlignment','Middle','Color','w');
       for j= 1:airports
            j=1;
            if Pax(i,j) >= cplex.Param.mip.tolerances.integrality.Cur
                l(n)    =   line([XX(i) XX(j)],[YY(i) YY(j)],'Color',clr(nc,:),'LineStyle',style{ns},'LineWidth',Flights(i,j));
                nc      =   nc + 1;
                if nc > size(clr,1)
                    ns      =   ns + 1;
                    nc      =   1;
                end
                txt{n}  =   ['A' num2str(i) '\leftrightarrow' 'A' num2str(j) ', ' num2str(Pax(i,j)) ' Pax, ' num2str(Flights(i,j)) ' Flight(s)'];
                n       =   n + 1;
            end

    end
    n       =   (n - 1);
    legend(l(1:n),txt{1:n},'Location','EastOutside');
    uistack(p,'top');
    uistack(t,'top');
    set(gcf,'Units','Centimeters');
    set(gcf,'Position',[10 2 25 16]);
```

txt is there twice. first txt{n}= ..... and then it is used in the legend function. 
What should i call txt or what should i do to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your condition `if Pax(i,j) >= cplex.Param.mip.tolerances.integrality.Cur` is never true, so `txt` never gets defined and when you try to use it as an argument to your `legend` function call, it quite rightly errors out, as it doesn't exist.

Put a break point before/after your inequality test and check your variables are what you expect them to be. Also check whether the inequality holds true.

Comment: yes you are right the pax(i,j) is a matrix with zeros. So this will indeed never be true!